# ROS2: RQT can not get message class for a user defined message

Tags: ros2, topic, rqt, custom-message, action

I can build a package used to define interfaces like messages, service and actions. I think everything is fine since I can show them using the usual command

```
ros2 interface show /my_interfaces_package/[msg,srv,action]/...
```

The problem rises when I want to monitor the feedback topic of one action of mine. I receive the following message

```
[ERROR] [1699959541.226777799] [get_message_class]: Malformed msg message_type: hri_interfaces/action/VideoTracker_FeedbackMessage
```

I checked the definition and it seems fine to me

```
# Request: string for the selected camera
string camera_id

---
# Result: success tracking the target feature
bool success

---
#Feedback: center of the tracked feature
geometry_msgs/Point center
```

I guess if it wasn't correct I wouldn't even be able to compile...

Is there something I am missing about custom messages and rqt?

Thank you!